# Login Foursquare Api using facebook credentials

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth, foursquare

I am having this problem while building one iPhone app that connects using Foursquare. Its works fine with me to connect by using foursquare credentials but now my client want facility to login foursquare using Facebook credentials just like foursquare is doing in their native iOS app as well as on Website.

For Login i am using foursquare v2 api with oAuth login.

Can any one help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: so nobudy from your family is in kapadvanj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Foursquare developers](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/foursquare-api/1KfCeG2ywnU/_UKoXhpgghkJ), "You can't use facebook credentials to access foursquare, you'll need the user to specifically authenticate your application to access their foursquare information".

Edited because I typed Facebook when I meant Foursquare